# How to move past eight sided blocks

Tags: zelda-mystery-of-solarus-dx

I have started playing [The Legend of Zelda: Mystery of Solarus DX](http://www.solarus-games.org/games/zelda-mystery-of-solarus-dx/), based on the free GPL Solarus game engine (not sure how this relates to other Zelda versions).

I am now stuck with something that assume should be quite basic but I have not figured out; how to move or remove the eight sided blocks that lie as obstacles several places.

[image: screenshots]

There is one inside the house next to the very starting point of the game, blocking access to a chest, which to me indicates that this is something that is considered relatively basic, but hitting with the sword or throwing a vase at it makes no difference, and trying to push it does not work.

Such blocks are spread out several places and until now I have just explored the parts I can access without solving this issue, but now when exploring the last unexplored dungeon there is one chest behind three such blocks which I am pretty sure contains a key needed to advance, and thus I am stuck.

So how to move past such blocks?

Comment: In the vanilla game, you need a Power Bracelet in order to lift those.  Unless the mod has changed that, that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I have not encountered such an item, but will be looking out for it.

Comment: Looks like this game also has the darker eight-sides stones. For those, you'll probably need an upgrade to the Power Glove (in the vanilla game, this was the Titan's Mitt).

Answer (score 3):

Revisiting a cave I eventually I found the required item, and it is called *iron gloves*. Found in a chest just inside which I did not have the key to first time visiting.

[image: screenshot]

Update: I have also found this wonderful list of [walkthrough videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CY1z5BGBSq0&list=PLzJ4jb-Y0ufyvGrqfDpotZHUvZrcswjGR) which I am sure will contain this information as well (only watched one episode yet).